# Are embedded document ids unique in the collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Mongoose schema that embeds another:

```
var EmbedSchema = new Schema({
  foo: String
});

var ParentSchema = new Schema({
  foo: String
  embeds: [EmbedSchema]
});
```

After instantiating and embedding a couple objects, I'll end up with something like this:

```
{
  "_id": "4f505a866e65f3896b00002c",
  "foo": "some value",
  "embeds: [
    {
      "_id": "4f505aa36e65f3896b000034",
      "foo": "some value 1"
    }, {
      "_id": "4f2eeb8f559757bf4f000001",
      "foo": "some value 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Are the `_id`s within the `embeds` unique across the collection? I was thinking of querying just using `embeds._id` to get the `Parent` if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow mongo to create your _id field then they will all be unique in that collection.

Answer (score 5):

Embedded documents are full blown documents so their `_id`s are not only unique within the collection, they are globally unique.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks! Do you happen to have handy where this is mentioned this in the official docs?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't mongo default to ObjectIds? I haven't seen any 32-character GUIDs in my documents.

Comment: @thatmarvin: Right, ObjectIDs are "pseudo-GUIDs" and four bytes shorter than GUIDs. The intent of both is the same at least. The first link (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-The%5CidField) is the best reference on this I could find.